# replace values of table from values of another table where both tables don't have same no of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables at the moment.

```
Table1
   +-----+----+
     id    val
     1     a
     2     b
     3     c
     4     d
     5     e
   +-----+----+
```

```
Table2
 +----+-----+
  id    val
  1     aa
  2     bb 
  3     cc
 +----+-----+
```

**I want a resultant table to look like this** replacing values in table1 from table2 like so and keeping the renaming intact

```
Resultant table
   +-----+-----+
     id    val
     1     aa
     2     bb
     3     cc
     4     d
     5     e
   +-----+-----+
```

I've tried the following code

```
UPDATE Table1 
   SET Table1.val = Table2.val 
   where Table1.id = Table2.id
```

but i get an error that

```
table2.id cannot be bound
```

Is there any other solution ? Bear in mind that both tables do not have same length

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving is because you haven't included the table in your FROM clause in your update statement.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.value = ISNULL(T2.value,T1.value)
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

The above code resolves the problem - you could also remove the ISNULL and change the join to an INNER join as below:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.value = T2.value
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f64b190dfa8f824b7f14c8dbbc1fc7b)

For further details see [the docs on update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you haven't included the `Table2` in the `FROM` clause, in order to replace the value of `val` of `Table1` by the value of `val` of `Table2`, you should include `Table2` in the join.

```
update t1 set t1.val = t2.val from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MERGE statement.  It's especially useful if Table2 is acting like a staging table from an external source and one day it's a superset of Table1 and then you want to add more rows.

```
MERGE Table1 AS T
USING Table2 AS S ON (T.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET val = s.val;
GO
```